# Getting all likes from a specific user on a news wall with fewer graph API calls

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Right now, my solution counting likes of a specific user is

Starting a recursive call on the `"/{user-id}/posts"` edge
Iterate through all posts
On each post iterate through each like on the likes edge
If someone knows a better, easier way with less graph API calls necessary, please let me know!

```
/*
*
*   Count my_user_id likes in wall of user "123"
*
*   ex: url = /123/posts
*   
*   setTimeout to avoid exceed api level rate limit, code 613
*/

function findMyLikes(url,my_user_id,count,callback) {
    console.log(url);
    FB.api(url, function (response) {
        if (response.data) {
            response.data.forEach(function (post) {
                //console.log(post);
                if (post.likes) {
                    post.likes.data.forEach(function (like) {
                        if (like.id == my_user_id) {
                            count++;
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }

        if (response.paging && response.paging.next) {
            setTimeout(function() {findMyLikes(response.paging.next,my_user_id,count,callback)},1000);
        } else {
            callback(count);
        }
    });

};
```

Comment: You might be better posting this on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for your reply. Can I move it over there, or should I delete it here, an start over at codereview?

Comment: I believe you have to create a new post. Don't think there's any way of just moving it.